# Kerberos integration issue's with hadoop HA

Tags: hadoop, kerberos

I have setup hadoop ha by using cdh 5 and tried to integrate kerberos with it.i could start namenode where kerberos kdc installed successfully.But second namenode startup with an error message..

```
java.io.IOException: Login failure for hdfs/rhel3.had.com@had.com from keytab /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs.keytab



2015-02-18 16:24:27,391 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Clients are to use mycluster to access this namenode/service.
2015-02-18 16:24:28,220 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.io.IOException: Login failure for hdfs/rhel3.had.com@had.com from keytab /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs.keytab
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:947)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.login(SecurityUtil.java:242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loginAsNameNodeUser(NameNode.java:560)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:579)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:754)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:738)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1427)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1493)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user



kinit works in the name node



[root@rhel3 ~]# kinit -kt /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs.keytab hdfs/rhel3.had.com
[root@rhel3 ~]# klist -a
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: hdfs/rhel3.had.com@had.com

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
02/18/15 19:47:52  02/19/15 19:47:52  krbtgt/had.com@had.com
        renew until 02/18/15 19:47:52
        Addresses: (none)
[root@rhel3 ~]#



hdfs-site.xml:

<property>
  <name>dfs.block.access.token.enable</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<!-- NameNode security config -->
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.keytab.file</name>
  <value>/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs.keytab</value> <!-- path to the HDFS keytab -->
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal</name>
  <value>hdfs/rhel3.had.com@had.com</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.kerberos.internal.spnego.principal</name>
  <value>HTTP/rhel3.had.com@had.com</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.web.authentication.kerberos.principal</name>
  <value>HTTP/rhel3.had.com@had.com</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.web.authentication.kerberos.keytab</name>
  <value>/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs.keytab</value> <!-- path to the HTTP keytab -->
</property>

core-site.xml:
<property>
  <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
  <value>kerberos</value> <!-- A value of "simple" would disable security. -->
</property>

<property>
  <name>hadoop.security.authorization</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

[root@rhel3 ~]# kinit -kt /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs.keytab hdfs/rhel3.had.com
[root@rhel3 ~]# klist -ef
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: hdfs/rhel3.had.com@had.com

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
02/19/15 17:26:33  02/20/15 17:26:32  krbtgt/had.com@had.com
        renew until 02/19/15 17:26:33, Flags: FRI
        Etype (skey, tkt): aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[root@rhel3 ~]#
```

Please let me know how to resolve the issue..

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem, in my case, it also report this: [Kerberos: check sum failed issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274281/kerberos-check-sum-failed-issue/31159462#31159462)

I fix it by apply FQDN to all addresses.